# How to include folders in document libraries when provisioning from a template

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, folder, pnp, provisioning

I have a SharePoint site that I am using as a template to create new SharePoint sites.

This site contains document libraries that include empty folders:

[image]

However, the site that gets created from the template does not include any folders in the document libraries:

[image]

I'm using PNP.Framework 1.9 to generate the template:

```
 using var context = await GetAndLoadCsomClientContext(templateSiteUrl);

    var handlersToProcess = _sharePointSettings
        .DefaultTemplateHandlers
        .Aggregate((result, item) => result | item);

    var creationInformation = new ProvisioningTemplateCreationInformation(context.Web)
    {
        HandlersToProcess = handlersToProcess,
        IncludeSiteGroups = true,
        IncludeTermGroupsSecurity = true,
        IncludeSiteCollectionTermGroup = true,
        IncludeSearchConfiguration = true,
        IncludeAllClientSidePages = true,
        ProgressDelegate = (message, step, total) =>
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Template Retrieval Progress: {step}/{total} - {message}");
        }
    };

    var template = context.Web.GetProvisioningTemplate(creationInformation);
```

and apply the template to the newly created site:

```
 using var context = await GetAndLoadCsomClientContext(siteCollectionUrl);

    var provisioningTemplateInformation = new ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation()
    {
        // Delay to wait for site creation SharePoint still performs tasks even though it says it's ready
        DelayAfterModernSiteCreation = _functionSettings.ProvisioningSecondsDelayAfterSiteCreation,
        MessagesDelegate = (message, ProvisioningMessageType) =>
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Provisioning Messages: {message}. Type: {ProvisioningMessageType}");
        },
        ProgressDelegate = (message, step, total) =>
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Provisioning Progress: {step}/{total} - {message}");
        }
    };

    context.Web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(provisionUsingTemplate, provisioningTemplateInformation);
```

The template gets applied correctly, it's just that the template doesn't include any folders under the lists. If I manually add folders to the lists in the template, those folders get created.

Answer (score 1):

By default GetProvisioningTemplate method will not support extracting Folder information from library.

For that you need to create custom extensibility handler and write your own logic.

I have created sample extensibility handler for you which extract folder information from "Shared Documents" Library and append it in template and then you can apply same template so it will create Folder structure as well.

Code sample for custom handler.

```
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

using PnP.Framework.Diagnostics;
using PnP.Framework.Provisioning.Extensibility;
using PnP.Framework.Provisioning.Model;
using PnP.Framework.Provisioning.ObjectHandlers;
using PnP.Framework.Provisioning.ObjectHandlers.TokenDefinitions;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PnPCustomHandler
{
    public class FolderItem
    {
        public string FolderName { get; set; }
        public string ParentUrl { get; set; }
    }
    public class FolderExtensibilityHandler : IProvisioningExtensibilityHandler
    {
        public ProvisioningTemplate Extract(ClientContext ctx, ProvisioningTemplate template, ProvisioningTemplateCreationInformation creationInformation, PnPMonitoredScope scope, string configurationData)
        {
            Web web = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(web);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            var templAllLists = creationInformation.BaseTemplate.Lists;
            foreach (var templist in templAllLists)
            {
                if (templist.Url == "Shared Documents")
                {
                    var spList = ctx.Web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + templist.Url);
                    ctx.Load(spList);
                    ctx.Load(spList.RootFolder);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                
                
                    ListItemCollection folderItems = spList.GetItems(new CamlQuery() { ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType'/><Value Type='Integer'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>" });
                    ctx.Load(folderItems);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    List<FolderItem> folders = new List<FolderItem>();
                    foreach (var folderItem in folderItems)
                    {
                        folders.Add(new FolderItem()
                        {
                            FolderName = Convert.ToString(folderItem["FileLeafRef"]),
                            ParentUrl = Convert.ToString(folderItem["FileDirRef"]).Replace(spList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, String.Empty).TrimStart(new char[] { '/' })
                        });
                    }
                    var parentFolders = folders.Where(f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.ParentUrl)).ToList();                    
                    foreach(var parentFolder in parentFolders)
                    {
                        templist.Folders.Add(GetPnPFolder(creationInformation.BaseTemplate, parentFolder, folders,string.Empty));
                    }


                }
            }
            return template;
        }
        private PnP.Framework.Provisioning.Model.Folder GetPnPFolder(ProvisioningTemplate template,FolderItem folderItem, List<FolderItem> allFolderItems,string parentUrl)
        {
            PnP.Framework.Provisioning.Model.Folder folder = new PnP.Framework.Provisioning.Model.Folder(folderItem.FolderName);

            parentUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentUrl) ? folderItem.FolderName : (parentUrl + "/" + folderItem.FolderName);

            var allChildFolders = allFolderItems.Where(a => a.ParentUrl == parentUrl).ToList();

            foreach(var childFolder in allChildFolders)
            {
                folder.Folders.Add(GetPnPFolder(template, childFolder, allFolderItems, parentUrl));
            }

            return folder;


        }
        public IEnumerable<TokenDefinition> GetTokens(ClientContext ctx, ProvisioningTemplate template, string configurationData)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void Provision(ClientContext ctx, ProvisioningTemplate template, ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation applyingInformation, TokenParser tokenParser, PnPMonitoredScope scope, string configurationData)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Code sample how to use it.

```
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

using PnP.Framework;
using PnP.Framework.Diagnostics;
using PnP.Framework.Provisioning.Extensibility;
using PnP.Framework.Provisioning.Model;
using PnP.Framework.Provisioning.ObjectHandlers;
using PnP.Framework.Provisioning.ObjectHandlers.TokenDefinitions;

using PnPCustomHandler;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CreateSiteFromTemplate
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                using (ClientContext sourceSiteContext = new AuthenticationManager("", @"", "", "").GetContext("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Template"))
                {
                    Web srcWeb = sourceSiteContext.Web;
                    sourceSiteContext.Load(srcWeb);
                    sourceSiteContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    Console.WriteLine(srcWeb.Title);
                    var assemblyName = typeof(FolderExtensibilityHandler).Assembly.FullName;
                    var handler = new ExtensibilityHandler()
                    {
                        Assembly = assemblyName,
                        Configuration = "",
                        Enabled = true,
                        Type = "PnPCustomHandler.FolderExtensibilityHandler",

                    };


                    var creationInformation = new ProvisioningTemplateCreationInformation(sourceSiteContext.Web)
                    {
                        ExtensibilityHandlers = new List<ExtensibilityHandler>() { handler },
                        IncludeSiteGroups = false,
                        IncludeTermGroupsSecurity = false,
                        IncludeSiteCollectionTermGroup = false,
                        IncludeSearchConfiguration = false,
                        IncludeAllClientSidePages = false,
                        ProgressDelegate = (message, step, total) =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Template Retrieval Progress: {step}/{total} - {message}");
                        }
                    };

                    var template = srcWeb.GetProvisioningTemplate(creationInformation);

                    using (ClientContext destSiteContext = new AuthenticationManager("", @"", "", "").GetContext("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/destSite"))
                    {

                        var provisioningTemplateInformation = new ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation()
                        {                                                      
                            MessagesDelegate = (message, ProvisioningMessageType) =>
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Provisioning Messages: {message}. Type: {ProvisioningMessageType}");
                            },
                            ProgressDelegate = (message, step, total) =>
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Provisioning Progress: {step}/{total} - {message}");
                            }
                        };

                        destSiteContext.Web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(creationInformation.BaseTemplate, provisioningTemplateInformation);
                        destSiteContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    }




                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Finished");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }


        }
    }


}
```

You can find sample solution which you can try at below link:

https://github.com/kavaghela/pnp-ExtensibilityHandler/tree/main/CreateSiteFromTemplate

Hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh, but one question: In the PowerShell version there is a flag for lists, includeItems. So here it's far easier to extract information from lists or libraries. Why doesn't this exist also for c#? Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/configuring-the-pnp-provisioning-engine

Answer (score 0):

The Provisioning system handles the list and the pieces of the list (views, content types, fields etc.) but doesn't seem to be able to include content.  Folders would be content.

I would suggest creating a script to add the folders such as:

```
Add-PnPFolder -Name NewFolder -Folder "Shared Documents"
```

This would create a folder called NewFolder in the Documents library of the connected site.